# Best-Practice: Using parameters vs. using assigned fields in constructor

Tags: c#, constructor

When you write a constructor in C# you usually take a few parameters and assign them to fields/properties in your class;

```cs
public class Foo {
    public Bar Bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Now lets say I want to further process the parameter, and do something with it, like this:

```cs
public class Foo {
    public Bar Bar;
    public FooBar fooBar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        Bar = bar;

        fooBar = new FooBar(bar.fooBarParameter);
    }
}
```

Now my question is, should I use the parameter `bar` or the field/property `Bar` in `new FooBar` or other code that uses the input. Are there even differences? If not which one is the default?

Comment: If `public Bar Bar` is a property, then referring to it from the constructor will go through the `get` accessor which is a method and may contain additional code, so you choose what to use based on whether you want that additional code to run. If `public Bar Bar` is a field, there is no difference.

Comment: If theres no difference for fields, is there a standard or convention for it?